# Draggable / floating Web Part Properties dialog

Tags: 2013, web-part, branding, style

I have a pretty tight design that has a fixed width. However, when editing a Web Part, the dialog gets cut off or sometimes doesn't get display at all because of the frame's overflow.

I would like to implement a floating Web Part properties dialog. Any suggestions on how to approach this and apply it across my site collection?

Answer (score 2):

If this is part of a page layout, you can have a separate stylesheet for edit mode that relaxes your fixed width or removes your branding altogether to make it easier to modify web part properties. You would use an [EditModePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.editmodepanel(v=office.15).aspx).

I've done things like this in page layouts:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" id="ContentDisplay" PageDisplayMode="Display">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mydisplaymode.css" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" id="ContentDisplay" PageDisplayMode="Edit">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myeditmode.css" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Comment: Alright. Let me give this a go. I'll check back asap. thx